# CXF annotation: how to be fault-tolerant?

Tags: java, jaxb, cxf, jax-ws, jaxb2

Is there an annotation to tell JAXB (or a configuration with CXF 3.1?) to be more fault tolerant?

DTO class attribute:

```
private List<Address> address;
```

Part of XML SOAP response parsed:

```
<address xsi:type="axis2ns185:anyType">
  <empty>true</empty>
</address>
```

Exception thrown:

```
Caused by: com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; ...; 
unexpected element (uri:"", local:"empty"). Expected elements are ...
```

I would like this scenario result in an empty list of Address...

Comment: Please [vote](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jaxb/synonyms) to make [tag:jaxb2] synonym of [tag:jaxb].

Answer (score 0):

To remove validation (and exceptions from validation) during parsing:

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
Map<String, Object> propertiesMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
propertiesMap.put("set-jaxb-validation-event-handler", "false");
factory.setProperties(propertiesMap);
```